# Open Google analytics dashboard by default

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website in google analytics and i've created handy dashboard. However when i open the website it goes straight to Audience > Overview screen.

I'd like it to open the dashboard by default once i click on the website, is that possible?

Comment: I'd like that too but it seems to not be possible.